# How to view the interactions of all categorical predictors in an OLS model using python's statsmodels?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I have successfully run an OLS model using the statsmodels package in python. However, the model pics one variable as an intercept, and does not include it in the results of interactions. Specifically, I have 5 levels in the "Meal_Cat" category below, and the model picks one of them ("Low" level) and treats it as an intercept. That is okay, but the problem is that I am unable to see its interactions with other categories (such as a Low by Group interaction).

See below for how the model is set up:

```html
model = ols('Cost ~ C(Meal_Cat)*C(Group)*C(Region) + Age + Gender', data= Mealcat_DF).fit()
# Seeing if the overall model is significant
print(f"Overall model F({model.df_model: .0f},{model.df_resid: .0f}) = {model.fvalue: .3f}, p = {model.f_pvalue: .4f}")
model.summary()
```

I was wondering if anyone can suggest for a way to include all terms from the model in the interaction summary.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example with seaborn's toy datasets such as tips. What you're look for is not really clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is already string or category variable, you just try the following.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

formula = 'tip ~ sex*smoker*day + total_bill'
model = smf.ols(formula, data=df)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    tip   R-squared:                       0.485
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.449
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     13.35
Date:                Mon, 20 Jan 2020   Prob (F-statistic):           8.29e-25
Time:                        14:21:24   Log-Likelihood:                -344.02
No. Observations:                 244   AIC:                             722.0
Df Residuals:                     227   BIC:                             781.5
Df Model:                          16                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=========================================================================================================
                                            coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                                 0.9917      0.357      2.777      0.006       0.288       1.695
sex[T.Female]                            -0.0731      0.506     -0.144      0.885      -1.071       0.925
smoker[T.No]                             -0.0427      0.398     -0.107      0.915      -0.827       0.741
day[T.Fri]                               -0.4549      0.487     -0.933      0.352      -1.415       0.506
day[T.Sat]                               -0.4662      0.381     -1.224      0.222      -1.217       0.284
day[T.Sun]                               -0.2880      0.423     -0.681      0.497      -1.121       0.545
sex[T.Female]:smoker[T.No]               -0.1423      0.593     -0.240      0.811      -1.311       1.026
sex[T.Female]:day[T.Fri]                  0.8553      0.737      1.161      0.247      -0.597       2.307
sex[T.Female]:day[T.Sat]                  0.2319      0.605      0.383      0.702      -0.960       1.424
sex[T.Female]:day[T.Sun]                  1.0867      0.772      1.407      0.161      -0.435       2.608
smoker[T.No]:day[T.Fri]                   0.1224      0.905      0.135      0.893      -1.660       1.905
smoker[T.No]:day[T.Sat]                   0.6258      0.480      1.303      0.194      -0.320       1.572
smoker[T.No]:day[T.Sun]                   0.2552      0.505      0.506      0.614      -0.739       1.250
sex[T.Female]:smoker[T.No]:day[T.Fri]    -0.2185      1.303     -0.168      0.867      -2.787       2.350
sex[T.Female]:smoker[T.No]:day[T.Sat]    -0.4487      0.759     -0.591      0.555      -1.944       1.046
sex[T.Female]:smoker[T.No]:day[T.Sun]    -0.7027      0.892     -0.788      0.431      -2.460       1.054
total_bill                                0.1078      0.008     13.951      0.000       0.093       0.123
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       29.744   Durbin-Watson:                   2.154
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               60.768
Skew:                           0.616   Prob(JB):                     6.38e-14
Kurtosis:                       5.112   Cond. No.                         629.
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```